# Moving Qt 5.3 app to Qt 5.5, 10k+ warnings, PRAGMA, '-Winconsistent-missing-override'

Tags: c++, qt

I am working on an app I was developing in Qt 5.3. It compiles with no warnings in 5.3.

If possible I'd like to bring it up to date with Qt 5.5.

Fortunately the app compiles in 5.5 no problem except that it throws over 10k warnings.

All of the warnings point to the Q_OBJECT macro.

`warning: unknown warning group '-Winconsistent-missing-override', ignored [-Wunknown-pragmas]
    Q_OBJECT
    ^`

I don't understand this warning. What does it mean and how can I fix it?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that a class uses 'override' for some of its methods and has methods that override base class methods but aren't marked override.

I found a bug report related to this issue [link](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-46903), it is marked as resolved (actually it is a duplicate of resolved one) so it should disappear with new release. Optionally you can disable this warning.

Comment: Thank you, very helpful.

Comment: You can accept this answer by pressing the green button on the left side of the answer.

Comment: Thanks, new to using SO.